# DRF - How to pass model object instance from view to my serializer data?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'd like to append an object field to my serialized data in internal value . How can I reference that object directly? In my view, I use get_object_or_404 , I tried passing the kwargs, args to my serializer but that didn't work.

serializer.py

```
class StringArrayField(serializers.ListField):
    def to_representation(self, obj):
        obj = super().to_representation(obj)
        return ",".join([str(element) for element in obj])

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        data = data.split(",")
        return super().to_internal_value(data)

class StockListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    stock_list = StringArrayField()

    class Meta:
        model = Bucket
        fields = ("stock_list",)
```

view.py

```
class EditBucketSymbols(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    serializer_class = StockListSerializer
    queryset = Bucket.objects.all()

    def get_object(self, queryset=queryset, **kwargs):
         item = self.kwargs.get('slug')
         return get_object_or_404(Bucket, slug=item)
```